# Laravel 4 namespaced controller routing with parameters

Tags: routes, namespaces, laravel-4

So I don't know if this is because my project is namespaced, but this is what I have in my routes:

```
Route::controller( 'videos/{type?}/{id?}', '\App\Controllers\VideoController@getIndex');
Route::get( 'videos', '\App\Controllers\VideoController' );

/** Home/Fallback Controller **/
Route::controller('/', '\App\Controllers\HomeController');
```

This is the url I'm going to:

mysite.com/videos/supplier/1

And this is my Video Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use \View;
use \Asset;
use \App\Models\Video;

class VideoController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex($filterType = null, $filterId = null)
    {
        Asset::addStyle('css/magnific-popup.css');
        Asset::addScript('js/magnific-popup.js');
        Asset::addScript('js/magnific-video.js');

        $video = new Video();

        $this->data['videoCategories'] = $video->getCategories();
        $this->data['videoSuppliers'] = $video->getSuppliers();

        if( $filterType == 'category' )
        {
            // grab videos by category id
            $this->data['videos'] = $video->getByCategory( $filterId );
        }
        elseif( $filterType == 'supplier' )
        {
            // grab videos by supplier id
            $this->data['videos'] = $video->getByCategory( $filterId );
        }
        else
        {
            // get all videos
            $this->data['videos'] = $video->getAll();
        }

        $this->data['currentId'] = $filterId;
        $this->data['currentType'] = $filterType;

        $this->layout->content = View::make('videos.index', $this->data);
    }

}
```

The getIndex method works fine when I go to mysite.com/videos... but when the parameters come into play, it won't find the other route. I think it's trying to find a nested controller like Controllers/Video/CategoryController@getIndex or something..
This is the error it's giving me:

> Class \App\Controllers\VideoController@getIndex does not exist

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your route file, try to change :

{type?} to {any} and {id?} to {num}

works for me...

or if you want more deep filters for {any} and {num}.
please understanding at docs in route parameters section (Route::pattern)

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

you can do like this :

```
// remove your @getIndex and change {type?} to {any}, {id?} to {num}
Route::controller( 'videos/{any}/{num}', '\App\Controllers\VideoController');
```

Comment: No it still throws the error when I do that.. is your project namespaced? I feel like that's what is messing it up although I don't see how it could..

Comment: ah, I thought you had wrong fill your route::controller

you should not write @getIndex in route::controller

see at here : http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Comment: Oh wow.. I accidentally switched the two when the bottom one should have been controller, not get.. Thank you... I feel stupid =/

Comment: Do you want to edit your answer to include that and I can mark it right?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your route using the action

```
Route::controller( 'videos/{type?}/{id?}', '\App\Controllers\VideoController@getIndex');
```

You should just:

```
Route::controller( 'videos/{type?}/{id?}', '\App\Controllers\VideoController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sory my bad engslish.

Make sure your sub folders names start with a lovercase letter located in app/controllers

**incorrect**

app/controllers/SubFolder

**correct**

app/controllers/subfolder

Comment: I think name of the Folder is not effect